# c# async await and exception

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, async-await

I wrote a visual studio 2015 c# program for reading from a custom Ethernet device some data. I need to use async await instructions because the data will be read all together on scheduled times.

I use a custom .NET library for read data; this is my code:

```
private void timerPollingData_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   readDevice_01();
   readDevice_02();
   // and so on for all devices ...
}

private async void readDevice_01()
{
   var result = await getDataDevice_01();
   // Save data
}

private async void readDevice_02()
{
   var result = await getDataDevice_02();
   // Save data
}

private Task<string> getDataDevice_01()
{
   MyCustomLibrary readDevice = new MyCustomLibrary.Master();
   return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => readDevice.ReadHoldingRegister(... some parameters ...).ToString());                       
}

private Task<string> getDataDevice_02()
{
   MyCustomLibrary readDevice = new MyCustomLibrary.Master();
   return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => readDevice.ReadHoldingRegister(... some parameters ...).ToString());                       
}
```

My doubt:
what is the best practice for handle exception of each Task? I need to understand what devices are unplug from Ethernet or switch off and then STOP the TASK  used to retrieve data from it.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: *DON'T* use `async void`, it's only for event handlers. You can't await it or catch any exceptions. Use `async Task` if you don't want to return anything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Good standard advice but the TimerTick _is_ an eventhandler. So the propagation into two `async  void` methods isn't great but not altogether wrong either.

Comment: We don't need to know which  Visual Studio but do tell us if this is a Windows service or WinForms or ... application.

Comment: As an advise, you could create a single `Master` that will get you Modbus data, and will log all info about inner exception's it get, while you request data.

Comment: You shouldn't use `async void` (use `async Task` instead), and you shouldn't use `Task.Factory.StartNew` (use `Task.Run` instead).

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid `async void`; use `async Task` for everything except async event handlers. For more information, see my article on [async best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Also, you should not use `StartNew`; it's a low-level, very dangerous API with inappropriate default parameter values. Use `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew`. For more information, see my blog post on [`StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

> I need to use async await instructions because the data will be read all together on scheduled times.

Asynchrony is one form of concurrency, which you can use with `Task.Run` **if** your device API does not have asynchronous methods:

```
private async void timerPollingData_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var task1 = readDevice_01();
  var task2 = readDevice_02();
  // and so on for all devices ...
  await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, ...);
}

private async Task readDevice_01()
{
  var result = await Task.Run(() => getDataDevice_01());
  // Save data
}

private string getDataDevice_01()
{
  MyCustomLibrary readDevice = new MyCustomLibrary.Master();
  return readDevice.ReadHoldingRegister(... some parameters ...).ToString();                       
}
```

If your API had a `ReadHoldingRegisterAsync` method, then this would be more naturally expressed as:

```
private async void timerPollingData_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var task1 = readDevice_01Async();
  var task2 = readDevice_02Async();
  // and so on for all devices ...
  await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, ...);
}

private async Task readDevice_01Async()
{
  var result = await getDataDevice_01Async();
  // Save data
}

private async Task<string> getDataDevice_01Async()
{
  MyCustomLibrary readDevice = new MyCustomLibrary.Master();
  var result = await readDevice.ReadHoldingRegisterAsync(... some parameters ...);
  return result.ToString();
}
```

> My doubt: what is the best practice for handle exception of each Task? I need to understand what devices are unplug from Ethernet or switch off and then STOP the TASK used to retrieve data from it.

The best practices for getting exceptions from tasks are to `await` them.

You don't have to worry about stopping a task after it raised an exception. By the time the task reports its exception, it has already stopped.

Comment: Hi Stephen,

thank you very much for sample code; i don't know if my custom library (or API) has or has not asynchronous methods for reading data. So, for now i try to modify my code like to first code sample. Next week i hope to make some test; then update this discussion with my results

thanks a lot